# USING CASE STATEMENT IN SQL LOADER CONTROL FILE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-loader

I have a control file that loads text to oracle but i am trying to strip first 3 digits of Phone number example  1-469-428-5920 to 469-428-5920, please see below control file. what should be the syntax?

I keep getting error below, Please help

thanks

---

```
options (ERRORS=1000, SKIP=2)
load data 
infile '/clients/vca2/data/API/ADHOC_LOAD/VCA_RP_Hospital_Website_Master_List_VCA.CSV'
replace
into table VCABARK_CDI_DV.RP_HOSPITAL_MASTER_LIST
fields terminated by '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' AND '"'
trailing nullcols
(
    HOSPITAL_EXT_NUMBER, 
    REGION, 
    HOSPITAL_NAME, 
    ADDRESS_1, 
    CITY , 
    STATE, 
    POSTAL_CODE, 
    PHONE "CASE WHEN SUBSTR(:PHONE,1,2) = '1-'  THEN ‘SUBSTR(:PHONE,3)’  ELSE ‘:PHONE’ END",
        RCF_PHONE,
    FAX , 
    EMAIL ,
    WEBSITE_CLASS, 
    DOMAIN, 
    SHORTNAME, 
    PMS, 
    INDICATOR_24_HOUR, 
    CARECLUB, 
    HOME_DELIVERY, 
    APPOINTMENT_CTA, 
    FREE_FIRST_EXAM, 
    AAHA , 
    AAFP_MEMBER, 
    CAT_FRIENDLY,
    FEAR_FREE , 
    LOW_STRESS, E
    VECCS, 
    FACEBOOK_URL, 
    GMB_URL , 
    YELP_URL, 
    BOOK_URL, 
    REQUEST_URL,
        HOURS_OPERATIONS_URL,
    HD_URL_SUBDOMAIN, 
    HD_URL_ORIGINAL, 
    PET_PORTAL_URL, 
    AIS_CLINIC_ID, 
    AIS_TOKEN
 )
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Why do you have the (curly) quotes around bits of the case expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't said what error you are getting, but you should have quotes - curly or otherwise - within your case expression. Instead of:

```
PHONE "CASE WHEN SUBSTR(:PHONE,1,2) = '1-'  THEN ‘SUBSTR(:PHONE,3)’  ELSE ‘:PHONE’ END",
```

use:

```
PHONE "CASE WHEN SUBSTR(:PHONE,1,2) = '1-' THEN SUBSTR(:PHONE,3) ELSE :PHONE END",
```

Comment: Thank you Alex for your response, please see error below                                                              SQL*Loader-291: Invalid bind variable :PHONE⡩n SQL string for column PHONE.

Comment: @okla - is that your original error? You should have got "ORA-00911: invalid character" from what you showed. Or are you saying you're getting that with my modified expression? I've just retested that and it's working OK... But that message looks weird towards the end, do you actually have control characters embedded in your expression, as well as curly quotes? Did you edit your existing string to look like mine, or copy-and-paste? (I assume the curly quotes are from copying from Word or something; wouldn't surprise me if there was other rubbish in there too *8-)

Comment: Alex,  I tried the solution above and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much! Appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just keep the last 12:

```
PHONE "SUBSTR(:PHONE, -12, 12)",
```